# Session_End does not fire even Session_Start saves data in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I still have the Problem, that Session_End does not fire. 
I make some simple log entry in Sesseion_End to make sure of it.

I Save lots of data in Session variable in Session_Start

and my web config contains:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1">
```

Who can help me, please?

edit: I was asked to post some code.

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          log.Debug("Session start of " + User.Identity.Name);
          Session["something"] = "something";
          ...
    }
```

...

```
    void Sesseion_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log.Debug("Session end of " + User.Identity.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some more Code!

Comment: No, because I wait till timeout.